# Как двигать фигуры когда на них нажимают

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста, напишите функцию, которая двигает объект, когда вы кликаете по нему.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что отсутствует в тексте отсутствует сам вопрос

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```js
$(function(){
  $('div').on('click', function(){
       $(this).animate({ top: "+=50", left: "+=20"
  }, 500, function(){
         var text = $(this).text() == 'PUK!' ? 'BOOM!' : 'PUK!';
         $(this).text(text);
       });
      });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script><div>div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Без использования *jQuery* на "чистом" *JavaScript*:

```js
function rnd(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1));
}

function onClick() {
    var div = document.getElementById("block");
    var maxX = 250 - div.style.width;
    var maxY = 150 - div.style.height;
    div.style.left = rnd(maxX) + "px";
    div.style.top = rnd(maxY) + "px";
}
```

```css
#block {
    background-color: green;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="block" onclick="onClick();"></div>
```